# How to auto login into website using AWS private repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, docker-registry

I have a private repository that I have already docker pushed my image into.

Here is my one image in this repository:
[image]

However, when I got into the url, this shows up

[image]

How do i make it so that this doesn't show up? (And also, what do the mean by username and password? my IAM user doesn't have a password, only access key id and secret key as far as I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to just copy the image link and paste into your browser.

You configured your username and password when you logined via docker (I'm assuming, since your image is successfully pushed)

This means that your username and password is configured WITHIN your docker container and NOT in the "real world" i.e. outside your docker container.

The next steps you should take are:

1. Pull that url as a docker image

`docker pull <url>`

^ the `<url>` is whatever the link in the photo is (can't see because it's censored)

2. `docker images`

From this command, find the image id of the image you just pulled

3. `docker run -d -p <port>:<port> <imageid>`
4. `docker ps` should help you figure out the correct link you should be copy and pasting into your browser.

Comment: Thanks haha, but docker ps didn't really help me figure out the correct link. I was, however, using flask to run my app, so flask did print out the "correct link" which was like 172.17.0.2:<port> or something like that. I'm not sure if this is "correct", but it sure isn't localhost. If this looks wrong to you, feel free to correct my mistake! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is push a docker image to ECR, which is just a storage service for docker images. You aren't running any docker containers at this point. This is no different than if you had pushed the image to DockerHub.

All AWS is doing for you right now is storing a file for you. To actually run a docker container based on that image you now need to deploy an ECS service using an ECS Task definition that references that image in ECR.

At no point should you be taking the ECR Image URL and placing that in your web browser's address bar. That image URL is a URL that Docker needs for downloading a copy of the docker image. It is **not** a web server URL for a web browser to visit.